# How to header stream_context_create?

Tags: php, http, curl

I have the following code:

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-type: text/html\r\n",
        'method' => 'POST'
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

This is not giving the appropriate result (no result at all), since the equivalent curl is:

```
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo $httpcode;

    return $data;
}

curl($url);
```

actually gives the actual result.

Since i'd like to avoid curl in production server, i'd really like the `file_get_contents` to work. To debug this, I have decided to examine the header for both curl and `file_get_contents`. In the curl code above, you can notice an `echo`, which prints the header:

> HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Length: 1564 Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 18:00:25 GMT Server:
>   GFE/2.0

I'd like to do the same for file_get_contents to examine its headers and hope fully see what is wrong. (you could point out what's wrong yourself if you like).

Comment: RTM? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php

Comment: @MarcB Can you provide an example wrt to my code above?

Comment: There is also something like `$http_response_header`. From docs: `When using the HTTP wrapper, $http_response_header will be populated with the HTTP response headers. $http_response_header will be created in the local scope.` See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://example.com/';
$data = ''; // empty post

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header' => "Content-type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
    'method' => 'POST'
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$fp      = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
$meta    = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "Failed!";
} else {
    echo "Success";
    $response = stream_get_contents($fp);
}

fclose($fp);
var_dump($meta);
```

To get the stream meta data, you will need to switch from `file_get_contents` to `fopen`.  It makes no difference as under the hood, PHP will connect and issue the response in the same way (using the `http://` wrapper).

If `php.ini` is set to disable [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), the both file_get_contents and fopen will be affected and won't be able to open remote URLs.  As long as this isn't the case, fopen of a URL will work the same way as file_get_contents; using fopen just gives you access to the stream which you can then call [`stream_get_meta_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) on.